# Indexes Gallery failed to render index list

Tags: lucene

I am new to sitecore and currently in sitecore developer training. Today I ahve faced weird issue and after trainer also not able to resolve, I think I should post in this forum.

I have added some custom search field to the solution. These fields also added in Lucene Default Search config. After deploying the solution, I am tried to rebuild index option from developer menu, However I am unable to see any Indexes list over there. I am getting message as "Indexes List Failed to Render"

Also I have tried

1. sitecore desktop-> Control Panel-> Indexing-> Indexing manager But
   Sitecore dialog box does not pop up.

   2. desktop-> Control Panel-> Database-> Rebuild index didnt work.
   3. IIS Reset.

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I would recommend you patch in a separate config with your custom index configuration than changing the default lucene index config. You may need to post your custom field configuration so we can figure out what's causing the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you patch in a separate config with your custom index configuration than changing the default lucene index config. You may need to post your custom field configuration so we can figure out what's causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help. I have now able to figure out what was going wronng. I have not made changes using patch and and messed up directly into the Sitecore.Content.Search.config instead of Lucene config. Because of this changes I am having Sitecore Configuration exception and that caused to indexes list disapper.

Comment: If you don't mind, please mark my comment as the accepted solution when I post it as an answer.

Comment: @Mohit Could you please post your config that solved the problem. It would help others too. Thank you.

Comment: @Qwerty If you have done any changes to Sitecore default search files.  Please replace all those files by copying from Sitecore base installation. If you have your customization in patch files, disable those patch files temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar [issue](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/7059/internal-search-doesnt-work-after-configuring-solr) and this worked for me

While integrating Solr, I disabled all Lucene configs and after that internal search wasn't working, and also no search indexes were visible in the developer tab. I enabled this config and its all good now

```
Sitecore.ContentSearch.Lucene.Indexes.Sharded.Master.config
```